# Can you broadcast dictionary definitions over numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a very simple example of random walk simulations using numpy. My professor insists that we use numpy's broadcast functionality instead of for loops as much as we can, and I want to know if it's possible to broadcast dictionary definitions.

e.g. I have the array [E W N S]. Running through that array using the dictionary would result in [[1, 0] [-1, 0] [0, 1] [0, -1]].

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def random_path(origin, nsteps, choices, choice_probs, choice_map):
    directions = np.random.choice(choices, size=(15,), p=choice_probs)
    print directions

def main():
    directions = ['N', 'S', 'E', 'W']
    dir_probabilities = [.2, .3, .45, .05]
    dir_map = {'N': [0, 1], 'S': [0, -1], 'E': [1, 0], 'W': [-1, 0]}
    origin = [0, 0]

    np.random.seed(12345)
    path = random_path(origin, 15, directions, dir_probabilities, dir_map)

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just ignore the actual directional labels and just store the directions as a `(4,2)` shaped numpy array? Then you would just index into that array directly.

```
def random_path(origin, nsteps, choices, choice_probs, choice_map):
    directions = np.random.choice(choices, size=(15,), p=choice_probs)
    return directions

dir_map = np.array([[0,1], [0,-1], [1,0], [-1,0]])
# Everything else is the same as defined by OP

path_directions = random_path(origin, 15, np.arange(4), dir_probabilities, dir_map)
path = dir_map[path_directions]
```

Now `path` is a `(15,2)` shaped numpy array containing the sequence of moves from the `dir_map`.